# Colored console output

Tags: c#, colors

I'm just beginning to learn C# and am curious if there is an ASCII way to get colored output in the terminal, for example:

In Ruby I can do this:

```
puts "\e[32mThis will be green\e[0m"
```

In JavaScript I can do this:

```
function say(input){ 
    console.log("\033[32m" + input + "\033[0m"
}

say("This will be green")
```

How can I do the same thing in C#?

Comment: Sure, see my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# you an use the following:

```
Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
Console.WriteLine("White on blue.");
Console.Read();
```

Remember you can also do this in JavaScript:

```js
console.log('%cHello world', 'background-color: #0000FF; color: #FFFFFF');
```

Run the code snippet and then look at the JavaScript console.

Answer (score 2):

In a Console App you can do

```
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
Console.WriteLine("Hi I'm green");
Console.Read();
```